# How do i create an if else statement to redirect to a mobile page?

Tags: mobile

I am new here and I self teach myself coding and html design.

I have found help with having an if/else statement to redirect to a mobile site.

My question is that i do not have a mobile url but i want to make a mobile styled page in my directory. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this but generally speaking one does not maintain two separate code bases -- one for mobile and one for everything else.  Instead you should try to make the design "responsive" so that it can modify itself based on the screen size of the device it's on.  There are a lot of places you can go for more information on responsive design but the kind of wellspring for all such things is the web site A List Apart.  So:
http://alistapart.com/ and specifically http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design (old article but great grounding in the basics).  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Back then, I had to launch the mobile version of the application when it was on a mobile device in [Caché programming language](http://docs.intersystems.com/cache41/prg/prgintro.html).

I just found the code I used and convert it to javascript, it should work [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yL1fym5s/)

```
userAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
listMobilAndTablet=["Android", "Tablet OS", "webOS", "iPhone", "iPad", "iPod", "BlackBerry", "IEMobile", "Opera Mini"];

$(document).on("click","button",function(event){
  $.each(listMobilAndTablet, function( index, value ) {
    if(userAgent.indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1){
        console.log("isMobile");
    } 
  });
});
```